# Performance Testing of APIs

Tags: jmeter

Please could someone suggest:

I need to performance test a few APIs. Which of the below methods will be better way of conducting the tests (trying to understand the pros and cons of various ways to run JMeter tests):

1. Create Ultimate Concurrency Thread groups using only Jmeter.
2. Buy Blazemeter, add the Jmeter scripts, create scenario and run the tests
3. Run the JMeter tests using Maven plugin as part of the build.

Thanks,
N

Answer (score -1):

Testing the performance of an API can be achieved by the above mentioned 3 ways.

- Open Source: (Standalone JMeter/Taurus)
- Cloud based solutions (Octoperf/Blazemeter)

If you are looking for an open source tool + you have your LG machine allocated + not gonna test with massive number of users - I would suggest to go with standalone JMeter/ taurus for your load testing solution.

If you are looking for an hassle free environment to manage all your test, LGs, reports, monitoring, etc then cloud based solutions like Blazemeter/Octoperf seems promising. This is going to cost you money and requires a port needs to be open for the solution to communicate with AUT.

For Scripting: You can use the same JMeter scripting in all 3 cases. Choosing a thread group requires what kinda test you wanna perform on your microsevrices.

Comment: Thx, any difference between Microsoft Azure load testing tool and BlazeMeter?

Answer (score -1):

1. In any case you will be using JMeter so points 2 and 3 don't really differ. The pro is that you don't have to pay. The con is that you need to manage your infrastructure yourself.
2. BlazeMeter provides easy way of launching a JMeter test so you don't have to worry about creating and configuring machines, installing JMeter, setting up [distributed testing](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/distributed-testing-in-jmeter), [real time monitoring](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/realtime-results.html) and [results comparison](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/360002658858-Comparing-Reports).
3. JMeter Maven Plugin makes the following processes easier:

   - installing JMeter
   - generating [reporting dashboard](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html)
   - returning non-zero [exit status code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exit_status) when acceptance criteria are not met